warning: [deprecation] getFromLocationName(String,int) in Geocoder has been deprecated
I get the above warning because I now have "complieSdk 34".
I found this here:
android geocoder void getfromlocation how to get addresses?
And tries to rewrite the lines.
Previously:
   try {
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "!!! geoLocate:IOException:" + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

Afterward:
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1, new Geocoder.GeocodeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGeocode(@NonNull List<Address> list) {
                    if (list != null) {
                        Address address = list.get(0);

                        Log.d(TAG, "!!! geoLocate:found a location:" + address.toString());

                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                        moveCamera(latLng);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "!!! geoLocate:location not found");
                    }

                }
            });
        } else {
            try {
                list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "!!! geoLocate:IOException:" + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        }


Apparently it didn't quite work out.
Can anyone help with that please
searched on stackoverflow and found this
android geocoder void getfromlocation how to get addresses?
